# How does boost::python work?Any ideas about the realisation details?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm a newbie to boost and one of its libraries which I can't understand it is Boost.Python. Can anyone explain me in details how does this interoperability achieved?In the documentation there only a few words about metaprogramming.
P.S. I tried to look code but because of my lack of C++ knowledge I didn't understand principles.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could always look at the code ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This didn't help. I need simple explanation

Comment: The Boost.Python implementation is a type identification and conversion system that interfaces with the Python [C API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/).  [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/internals.html) link provides some very high-level information about what the implementation does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to interoperate:

1) from a "Python process", call functions written in C++.

Python already has a system to load dlls, they're called "extension modules". Boost.Python can compile your source to produce one. Basically you write a little wrapper to declare a function callable from Python, and the "metaprogramming" is there to do stuff like detecting what types the C++ function takes and returns, so that it can emit the right code to convert those from/to the equivalent Python types.

2) from a "C++ process", launch and control the Python interpreter.

Python provides a C API to do this, and Boost.Python knows how to use it.